# WebdriverIO with devtools is printing a lot of data in console

Tags: javascript, logging, puppeteer, webdriver-io, devtools

Currently I am working with web driver in order to get the trace of the devtools in a session with the following script:

```
   browser.startTracing()
    $(visitWebsiteBuilder).click()
    browser.pause(10000)
    browser.endTracing()
    fs.writeFileSync('trace.json', JSON.stringify(browser.getTraceLogs()))
```

It seems to work fine but the execution is generating a lot of logs in the console:

```
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 11488,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 15860,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 17180,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 17216,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 17200,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 15884,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 15148,
  tid: 9644,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 16312,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 15372,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 13752,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 4852,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 14476,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 16380,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 8300,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 5108,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 7568,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 13168,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 13768,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 17864,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 10796,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 16392,
  tid: 6432,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 15148,
  tid: 16248,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'thread_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 3036,
  tid: 8136,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'process_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 4488,
  tid: 0,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'process_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 15148,
  tid: 0,
  ts: 0
},
{
  args: [Object],
  cat: '__metadata',
  name: 'process_name',
  ph: 'M',
  pid: 3036,
  tid: 0,
  ts: 0
},
```

And a lot of info related to the browser. I have tried to changes the logging level in the **wdio.config.js** with the following options:

```
  // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
logLevel: 'silent',
//
// Set specific log levels per logger
// use 'silent' level to disable logger
logLevels: {
    webdriver: 'silent',
    devtools: 'silent'
},
```

but it stills printing that data and it floods the console, any idea about how to avoid this?

**UPDATE #1**
I tried to specify the log folder and now it is logging and creating the log files, but it stills printing the trace in the console:
[EvidenceScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brBCm.png)

**UPDATE 2**
Adding the package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "event_tracker_nhs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx wdio wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^6.4.6",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.4.5",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^6.5.2",
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^6.3.6",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.4.4",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^6.4.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.4.0",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.4.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chromedriver": "^84.0.1",
    "devtools": "^6.4.4",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3",
    "mocha.parallel": "^0.15.6",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.3",
    "webdriverio": "^6.4.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^0.19.2",
      "request-promise": "^4.2.6"
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to raise an issue to https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio

Answer (score 0):

**LE-02:** I am running `wdio-v5` currently, but either way, the behaviour should be the same. We can try another thing, seeing as you are using `chromedriver` to run your checks, you can go and override the `chromedriver` service log settings:

```
services: [
  ['chromedriver', {
      logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log', // >> your log file name
      outputDir: 'driver-logs',             // >> this will overwrite config.outputDir
      args: ['--silent']
  }]
],
```

---

If you don't want your browser logs to be dumped in the console, make sure you setup the **[outputDir](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html#outputdir)** option inside your `wdio.conf.js` file.

What will the effects be? Quoting the DOCS:

> Directory to store all testrunner log files (including reporter logs and wdio logs). If not set, all logs are streamed to stdout. Since most reporters are made to log to stdout, it is recommended to only use this option for specific reporters where it makes more sense to push report into a file (like the junit reporter, for example).

So just add `outputDir: '<folderPath>',` inside the `wdio.conf.js` file and you'll get the `browser` & `webdriver` log files in the given folder.

After you set it up, you should see the `wdio` log files inside the designated folder.

[image]

---

**LE-01:** I just ran your commands and the logs are pipped accordingly to the `wdio-0-0.log` file.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for answer my question, I tried your suggested approach and now it create the log files, but stills printing trace in console

Comment: @JeffersonLoria, I just ran your commands having configured a `outputDir` path and all the Chrome DevTools are piped as expected to the `wdio-0-0.log` file. Please update your question with WDIO versions & `package.json` info. What `wdio` version are you on?

Comment: I just added the package.json info, I am using the 6.4.6 wdio version

Comment: @JeffersonLoria, I've added another direction you can try: overwriting logging for the `chromedriver` service. If this doesn't bear fruit, you might want to see if the `getTraceLogs()` implementation for `v6` also has a forgotten `console.log` somewhere, or if you forgot about some `console.log`s in your codebase printing the output. Else, it should all go inside your `wdio-0-0.log` file.

Comment: That snippet should be in the services of wdio.config.js right?

Comment: I checked my code a lot of times looking for a miss console.log, and I dont have it. Also checked that getTraceLogs(), and it does not seems to be printing the trace directly to the console.

Comment: Yes @JeffersonLoria, correct, in the service section from the `wdio.conf.js` file.

Comment: It does not work either, I am thinking about try to downgrade to wdio 5.X

Comment: Tried downgrading wdio and it does not work either.

Comment: Hmmm @JeffersonLoria, maybe something else is in play. I'll think about it man. Can you update the logs to see which type of logs are being dumped in the console?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your situation and the different versions of WebdriverIO, but you can try:

```js
  const browser = await remote({
    capabilities: {
      browserName: "chrome"
    },
    logLevel: "silent"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing log level in the capabilities section, it works for me

```
capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 1,
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    logLevel:"silent"
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I had the same issue. The example wdio.conf seems to have been updated to include another service in the `logLevels` example. I changed mine to this to fix it.

```
logLevel: "warn",
logLevels: {
  webdriver: "warn",
  "@wdio/devtools-service": "warn",
},
```